# In Firestore can there be duplicates of FieldValue.serverTimestamp()?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Imagine you have thoiusands, even millions of users connecting simmultaneously on your Firebase app. Your app (on every single user) write this to Firestore:

```
const ref = firestore.collection('users').doc(myUID)
ref.set({
    updatedAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
})
```

Is it possible (even if very improbable) that more than one user has the same timestamp in updatedAt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee of uniqueness for server timestamps.  That said, I imagine it's highly unlikely to get a duplicate, since they are measured to nanosecond precision.